# Chrome doesn't disable submit button with span

Tags: html, google-chrome

If I have a submit button with a span inside it, it looks like Chrome still allows the span to be clicked when the button is set to disabled.

```
<form method="post" action="/changestatus" id="yw0">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="5">
  <input type="hidden" name="status" value="enabled">
  <button type="submit" disabled="disabled">
    <span>Submit</span>
  </button>
</form>
```

The preceding code works as expected in Firefox, but not in Chrome.

Any ideas on fixing this (without JS if possible).

Thanks!

Comment: In my Chrome (17) it works as expected. The button is disabled. What makes you think the button is not disabled? Can you post the rest of the form?

Comment: I've updated the question to show the entire form. I'm using Chrome 16. When I click on the button, the form is still submitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For submitting the form it does not `submit` in either browser (*as it should*).

If, though, with ***allows the span to be clicked*** you mean javascript firing the `click` event when clicking on it, then indeed there is a difference on how they handle this case.. (*you will have to handle it through javascript*)

Comment: Thanks, your anwser led to finding a leftover JS file that should not have been there ... Chrome does indeed treat the click differently than Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the form to submit you can add this code to your form element.

```
<form onSubmit="return false;">
```

I know its a JavaScript fix, but it is one.